# How to raise the number of active tasks in spark databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm in a configuration of databricks with 1 work, which gives a cluster two nodes and 12 cores each. The distribuition of this is stage is almost 2 per cluster. I tried to raise the number of works in Databrics to 4 workers and number of runnings (active tasks) raised to 8.
I searched over the internet and got no answer. i'm new in pyspark too.

There's any way to grow this number without need to scale the number of workers?

[image: Runnings image]

Comment: What's your use case? Are you facing any challenges with the existing configuration?

Comment: I'm doing a cartesian product and mapping the result. Both functions are working in a RDD partitioned.

Answer (score 1):

As per your existing configuration, it depends on the way you partitioned. But if you are having a finite number of partitions, use the below code to execute.

```
val input: DStream[...] = ...
val partitionedInput = input.repartition(numPartitions = your number of partitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue or missconfiguration in spark (or databricks). The problem was solved running the same code on a cluster without gpu. It went from 2 runnings to 20.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).